# Automatically populate combobox with column names from a database

Tags: c#, database, combobox

I'm trying to make a ContractManagementSystem application.

```
dbh.openCon();

SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, CONTRACTNUMBER, PORTALID, PRICEPERGB, MINIMUMSTORAGECAPACITY, STARTDATE, MINIMUM CONTRACT DURATION, BILLINGPERIOD, INCASSO, ACTIVE FROM BACKUPCONTRACTS", dbh.getCon());
SqlDataReader reader;

reader = com.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("CONTRACTNUMBER", typeof(string));
dt.Load(reader);

cb_Choices.ValueMember = "Id";
cb_Choices.DisplayMember = "ContractNumber";
cb_Choices.DataSource = dt;

dbh.closeCon();`
```

This is my code so far for adding the database items into a `ComboBox` named `cb_Choices`.

As you might be able to see, my sqlcommand is quite long. I was wondering if there is a way to automatically add items to the `ComboBox` because I have to do the same thing for about 12 other database tables.

If you're wondering what `dbh` is that is my `DatabaseHandler Class`.
The application is made in c# using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

If any other code is required please tell me and I will edit the post.

EDIT:

I saw some confusion in the comments so I thought I´d clear that up.
What I want to do is get the names of the columns from the database.

Example

### [image: Example 1]

In this case I would want the yellow painted items to show in the `cb_Choices`

Comment: You're going to need data access code somewhere. Whether it is where you have it or in a repository class, there is no getting around it. You could shorten the code with an ORM like Entity Framework but nothing is automatic. Regarding your query, if that command only exists for that combobox, you only need to select the first two fields, you can remove all the others.

Answer (score 0):

Try Data Binding. Checkout some links below

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mEHl0Fzsq3w

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AVZPTzkQOcY

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb655884%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to get away with not specifying the column names. Although you can try something like this for re-usability. And what happens with the database connection if an exception occurs? You would need to ensure the connection gets closed on failure as well.

```
public void PopulateCombo(ComboBox combo, 
    string tableName, string keyColumn, string valueColumn)
{
    dbh.openCon();

    try
    {
      var com = new SqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT {0}, {1} FROM {2}", keyColumn, valueColumn, tableName) , dbh.getCon());
      var reader = com.ExecuteReader();
      var dt = new DataTable();

      dt.Columns.Add(keyColumn, typeof(string));
      dt.Columns.Add(valueColumn, typeof(string));
      dt.Load(reader);

      combo.ValueMember = keyColumn;
      combo.DisplayMember = valueColumn;
      combo.DataSource = dt;
    }
    finally
    {
      dbh.closeCon();
    }
}

PopulateCombo(cb_Choices, "BACKUPCONTRACTS", "ID", "ContractNumber");
PopulateCombo(cb_Other, "Other", "OtherID", "OtherValue");
```

Comment: This is almoast what I need. In my code this method takes the items in the columns. What I need is the Names of these columns in the combobox.

Comment: I've modified my post hope that makes it more clear.